# Expand Range of Numbers with SQL in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So, I am a logistics engineer and I am trying to help my pricing manager build a pricing application tool that will help eliminate her time spent filling in huge excel files with information about pricing bids. I have successfully build an Access form that fills in the areas she wanted filled in but I come across a new problem now:

Every once in a while she will receive an RFP (Request for Proposal) which has a cluster of zipcodes. For example:

[image]

Now to make her bids, she has to manually create rows for each of the numbers in the range. Say for the 850-865 range, she has to make rows for 850, 851, 852, ... 865.

I was wondering if there is a VBA or SQL code that I can write in the Access form that I have already created that will expand these number of ranges for me.

I want it to be able to give me this just by the press of a macro button:

[image]

SIDE NOTE: For that second range of zip codes (929-948, 950-953, 956-958) how would you compile the code so that it expands all the ranges after the comma?

If you can help me with this you'd be an absolute life saver!!

The name of my table with this information is tblTemplate.

Thank you all!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Which DBMS are you actually using? You have tagged three. And your data is the real issue here. You have violated 1NF by stuffing multiple values into a single cell like this.

Comment: What happens with the created rows? Are they stored in a table or just temporary? If you store them, there is a table with a row field and a RFP reference field? Then you can `Split`  the ZIP-Code values on `,`and `-` and create an SQL Insert between them.

Comment: @SeanLange so sorry! I am new to this. I am using access as my database MS. The violation of the 1NF is something we cannot control because she receives her files like that from her customer, and then from there has to manually create new rows for the location of the zip code.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Yes, they are stored in the table. Right now, when she receives an RFP from a customer, she will receive a cluster of zipcodes, from there she manually creates new rows and assigns the specified location to the zip code. If I can just find a way to have sql or vba expand the range of clusters and put them into new rows, then my initial queries will be able to fill in the rest of the information. The issue is just being able to expand the cluster range into separate rows. Thanks!

Comment: For sure the data was normalized proper and they just crippled it. Now we have to clean it again. For sure you gave one table for the RFPs and only one table for the  rows (not one for each RFP) with RFPs table PK as FK. Need code for creating the inserts or is the split hint enough?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher what does PK and FK stand for? And if it easy for you to write an insert code that would be so helpful thanks!

Comment: `Primary Key` and `Foreign Key` are basic sql knowlegde. Search for them. As you get serveral RFPs you store them in a taböe and refence them by the PK of this table. In the table with rows you yust store the PK of the RFP (As FK) to know to which RFP the row belongs (they are not unique for sure). Add a combined unique index (search that too) on the FK and the row number  to prevent double rows for a RFP.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher oh yes I'm familiar now lol I just havent seem them abbreviated like that in a while! So this cannot be executed with a query code? It must be done through VBA?

Comment: There should be a pure sql solution. but I don't know and to extract the ranges is easy with split and loops in vba. As I commented on Alberts answer, I would create an sql insert statement while looping through the arrays, but that depenfs on your preferences unless we talk about > 100000 rows.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I have updated the pictures and added one of what I would like the outcome to be if you would like to take a look

Comment: Instead of updating pictures use text (almost always!). You can easy [create tables with markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Is `Zip Range` unique to `Origin City`? if yes just store the Zip/City relation in a table and look it up. If not store City/Destination in a table and just store the PK of this as FK in the rows table (like the RFP that I am missing, as you need to know which RFP the row data belongs)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher
Performance will not be faster. For say 1000 input records, you have to execute “at least one” insert (that might insert 1-20 rows). However, the “cost” of one sql execute/insert is about 10,000 reocrdset rows. Once I opened the reocrdset then I don’t have that “open” cost. Nor penalty of sql parser (syntax checking), nor query plan being created. The recordset will run 10x or better. OpenRecordset cost is about 10,000 rows (same as one sql execute). After that, code will run absolute circles around multiple separate sql statements unless each insert was about 10,000 rows.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I made completly opposite experience. Do you have a link to an example with testdata? Of course I use `db.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError` no direct usage of `CurrentDb` (only as Ref or With) what is slow.

Comment: @nabusafe please tidy up your comments (delete the thank you' s (Albert has seen it, instead vote for his answer and if it is your solution accept it! Some comments should update your question to make it more clear.). And you still didn't replaced the images with text data.

Comment: @ComputreVersteher -  I get about 20x, or a bit more by using reocrdsets. (so 20 hours vs my 1 hour). You get even greater speed results when using sql server as back end. Here is a link - use the defaults to create data - then try each button (2 times to remove some caching  - the data sample only takes about 2 seconds of run time    https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avrwal_LV4qxhpYAL_vyrfjN06FPEw

Comment: Access as front end to mySQL will also yield same speedup, perhaps even more. Issue is executing one sql statement - if that statement can update many rows, then it better then one recordset. If you execute "many" sql statements, then the reocrdset is faster (due noted syntax check, query plan build etc). And not clear what "empty line" edit you mean? If you mean the change in code? Well, you changed 2 lines of code into 4 - hardly any savings? Each "currentdb" execute is a cost of LESS then 1/1000th of a second. Your change saves 1/1000th of a second and is 2 extra lines of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179680/discussion-between-computerversteher-and-albert-d-kallal).

Answer (score 1):

You can write some code to do this. The amount of code is not long, but it is “tricky” code.

The following code would be “close” to what you need. The following code is “air code”. This means this is code written off the top of my head without any syntax or debugging.

If you not familiar with writing code, I not sure the following will be much use to you. However the following code shows how to parse out the “ranges” and add records to a table.

So you can do this, but you NEED the ability to write some VBA code. As noted, the following is the base outline how such code could be written:

```vb
Sub ParseOut()

   Dim rst          As DAO.Recordset    ' input talbe
   Dim rstOut       As DAO.Recordset    ' output (expanded rows)
   Dim strBase      As String
   Dim strOutPut    As String

   Dim rZip         As Variant
   Dim rZips        As Variant
   Dim rStart       As Integer
   Dim rEnd         As Integer

   Dim oneRange     As Variant
   Dim range        As Integer

   strBase = "tblRanges"

   strOutPut = "tblOutRange"

   With CurrentDb() ' added this to reach min chars for edit, but this saves one CurrentDb (for sure 0,005 secs)
     Set rst = .OpenRecordset(strBase)
     Set rstOut = .OpenRecordset(strOutPut)
   End With

   Do While rst.EOF = False

      rZips = Split(rst!ZipCodes, ",")
      For Each rZip In rZips
         oneRange = Split(rZip, "-")
         If LBound(oneRange, 1) = 0 Then
            ' no "-", so single value
            rStart = oneRange(0)
            rEnd = rStart
         Else
            ' start/end range
            rStart = oneRange(0)
            rEnd = oneRange(1)
        End If

        ' add the range to the table
        For range = rStart To rEnd
           rstOut.AddNew
           rstOut!City = rst!City
           rstOut!State = rst!State
           rstOut!Zip = range
           rst.Update
         Next range
      Next rZip

      rst.MoveNext 
   Loop

   rst.Close
   rstOut.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I would have looped through the arrays and concated the numbes to a value list that gets inserted at once. `Insert Into tableRows (FkRfp, Row)  Values (rfpKey, 850),  (rfpKey, 851), ...,(rfpKey, 865)`

Comment: The code to concatenate the list up correctly will take as much or more code then I written. And it not going to run any noticeable faster. If you have a shorter version and something more readable then what I posted, then by all means post your code and we can compare the two approaches.

Comment: Hum, just added that tag - I don't see any difference in the results. I thought the indentation looked quite fine from the get go - you sure this is not your browser ?

Comment: Ah ok - I see the change. All it did was add some "color" to the tags - it did not change nor touch the indenting. Indents might not be perfect to one's liking here, but it looks rather fine to me. Perhaps I am missing something here?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of what I would like my outcome to be just by slicking a macro button that will give me that output @AlbertD.Kallal

Comment: Ok, the code I have assumed two tables (one for data you just imported and then we run the code to send new records (rows) out to the working table. I assume you have “many” rows of data in the working table, and having to process every single row that already exists in that larger table does not make the most sense. Code could be modified to run on the one table as opposed to two tables (input and output). What should the processing do with all the older existing records? Perhaps the data is just in some sub form? - that thus could work well.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Well the goal is to have a linked Access/Excel table in my DB and from there is updated continuously when new information is put into the linked table. So there is 2 tables in a way. I have the original information, then I will run my codes that will give me a table output exported into excel. The picture I have attached is the information that is being inputted into the linked excel sheet that will then show up in my Access DB.

Comment: Perfect then, as I noted, my code has a input table, and a output table. So your input is the excel sheet with the new rows, and the output is the access table with the expanded records. So my code is quite much what you need here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I will give it a go in just a bit. Thanks so much!

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Is there a way I can reach out to you personally so we don't have to keep going back and forth on this forum? I have a couple of questions about what is going on.

Comment: The whole idea here is for everyone to learn - else it becomes just work for me, and the community gains little or nothing here. I have a working sample here you can download and try:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avrwal_LV4qxhpYAL_vyrfjN06FPEw

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I'm sorry it says your link is unavailable, if you could please reupload it so I can take a look at it and play around with it that would be very very helpful.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal it still is not working :/ here is my email nabusafe@gmail.com if you can send it specifically there. I am desperate at this point lol